# MySQL query with where clause for column with special character

Tags: mysql

I am trying to filter the table by using where clause for a column with special characters and dT as float in MySQL

I am having a MySQL table with one of the column names having special character'.' The column accepts float value. the column name is 'box.length'. I tried the below query but it is not retrieving any result.

```
Select count(*) from `sample_table`
Where `box.length`='3.2'
```

I have manually checked and found that there are 17 rows meeting that criteria.

DB column count:
[image: DB column count]

Count displayed from my query:
[image: count displayed from my query]

Can someone correct me what is wrong in this & suggest a solution?
Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: which special character i can't see one. PLease add some sample data as text and the python code you are using

Comment: When referring to "special character" in this context, it's specifically pointing to the '.' (DOT).

Comment: Think it is due to the comparison of the float value with the string. Can you please try the below query: Select count(*) from 'sample_table'
Where 'box.length'= 3.2;

Comment: @nbk the question is clear, try reading the whole question

Comment: Yes correct. the '.' in the "box.length" is the special character that i am referring

Comment: all between two backticks is escaped so that should be a problem if your coumn actaully is box.length, but your tbale has not such a column so what is box.length?

Answer (score -1):

After trying it again, i found a way to get a result!

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sample_table` WHERE ROUND(`box.length`, 1) = 3.2;
```

`COUNT(*) = 1`

The problem appears to be because of MySQL's floating-point precision. Because of how floating-point numbers are stored, tiny differences in their values might occur, resulting in surprising results (Count = 0 even though it should be 1) when comparing them.

To avoid this problem, round the values before comparing them in your SQL query with the ROUND function.

Comment: see https://dbfiddle.uk/9J7YNpWf

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `sample_table` 
WHERE `box.length` = 3.2

tried this as well but still getting no rows.

Comment: it is unclear,. add datatable data and python ocde as text

Comment: thanks for the fiddle link. I tried it and found that for both "= 3.2" & "= '3.2'" i am getting count as zero, but when given without any where clause, i see count as 1.

Comment: @nbk btw how is it unclear if I can **clearly** tell what he is explaining?

Comment: @nbk yes it does, https://ibb.co/BBD3kxD and https://ibb.co/Yb1C9QT .Maybe you should check things before you say they don't work, just a little tip :)

Comment: @MahalakshmiK did it work?

Comment: @Karo - Yes. this issue got resolved. Thanks